# SqlReader, Repeater controls and CommandArgument problem

Tags: c#

I have a repeater control that generates a list of links from a SqlReader. I'm trying to create a button alongside each link that will allow the user to delete that link. My original thought was to use the <%#Eval("URL") %> expression in the Item template like below. However the CommandArgument in the ItemCommand method would always come back empty.

```
<asp:Repeater  ID="rptLinks" runat="server" onitemdatabound="rptLinks_ItemDataBound" 
                 onitemcommand="rptLinks_ItemCommand">
<ItemTemplate><a href="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "URL") %>" target="_blank"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "URL") %></a><asp:ImageButton visible="false" ID="btnDeleteLink" runat="server" ImageUrl="/Images/DeleteIcon.gif" CommandName="DELETE" CommmandArgument=<%#Eval("URL") %> />
</ItemTemplate>
<SeparatorTemplate><br /></SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

The next thing I tried was to use the ItemDataBound event to programatically set the CommandArgument, but I can't figure out what to cast the e.Item.DataItem into so I can reference the ["URL"] Item.

```
protected void rptLinks_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton btnDelete;
    btnDelete = (ImageButton)  e.Item.FindControl("btnDeleteLink");
    if (btnDelete != null)
    {
        btnDelete.Visible = (bool)ViewState["LinkEditing"];

        string URL = ((WhatTypeGoesHere)(e.Item.DataItem))["URL"].ToString();
        btnDelete.CommandArgument = URL;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the `DataItem` to any of the classes in your reader's inheritance chain that implement `IDataRecord`:

```
// You could also cast to SqlDataReader, DbDataReader, or IDataReader
string URL = ((IDataRecord)(e.Item.DataItem))["URL"].ToString();
```

Data readers are a bit confusing, because objects that inherit from `DbDataReader` can act as both a data source (through its implementation of `IEnumerable`) and as the object representing your data (through its implementation of `IDataRecord`).

The `IDataRecord` interface provides access to the column values of a data reader's records (via the `Item` property and the various `Get`* methods).

In other words, it's like you're binding to an `IEnumerable<IDataRecord>` (though not really, because `DbDataReader` implements the non-generic version of `IEnumerable`).

Comment: Just a comment:
Shouldn't it be possible to get the ["URL"] value without knowing the type of the datasource? Let say in the future I want to change the datasource to a datatable or some xml structure, isn't there a way to write the ItemDataBound code so it's agnostic and will work with any data source?

Comment: Updated my answer to explain why that isn't at issue here - basically, you're not tying your ItemDataBound code to your data source, but to your object.